# Can I surrender my green card and apply for a multiple-entry tourist visa?

Tags: usa, tourist-visas

I am a green card holder but after a year here in the United States I decided to go back to my native country. Can I surrender my green card and apply for multiple entries since I want to travel as a tourist more than a US citizen?

Comment: Note that surrendering your green card does not guarantee you will get a visitor visa. Your visa application will be judged like any other visitor visa application from a foreigner, including requiring you to convince the officer that you do not intend to immigrate on the visa.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can surrender your green card, and yes,  you can apply for a multiple-entry tourist visa.  You would file [Form I-407, Record of Abandonment of Lawful Permanent Resident Status](https://www.uscis.gov/i-407), and then you would apply for your visa using the online [DS-160](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application.html).  You'll also need to schedule an interview appointment at a US embassy or consulate.

You may want to consider the tax implications of doing this; questions about that would be off topic here, but you could ask at [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) or [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/).